# Getting a TypeError (tuple assignment) in one interpreter, and not the other

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pycharm, tuples, ubuntu-16.04

I am having an odd issue that I can't explain. I have some code that I wrote in PyCharms on my laptop, and tested it pretty thoroughly (I thought). I've now migrated to an Ubuntu environment, setup my virtualenv, installed my modules, and started testing...

With the same test in PyCharms and Ubuntu, I get two seperate results I can't explain. I need the Ubuntu version to work but can't see why it doesn't like my Tuple assignments when PyCharms and the interpreter there didn't care this whole time.

Ubuntu environment: using Python 3.6.5
Windows 10 environment: using Python 3.6.5 (via Python download)

My script fails here:

```
if something[7] is None:
    something[7] = "N/A"
```

Error from Ubuntu:

```
[2018-09-13 19:49:28,706] ERROR [__main__.main:445] Problem occurred. Please see log!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "script.py", line 320, in main
      something[7] = "N/A"
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Here is the actual tuple that PyCharm's interpreter modifies without an issue. I can see this in my debug:

```
('Val', 'Val', 'Val', 'Val', 'Val', 'Val', 'Val', 'N/A', 'Val', None, None, None, None, None, None)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error says it all. Tuple elements can&#39;t be changed. You need to make `something` a list or other object. I don't see how it could have worked elsewhere though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign an item to tuples, however, you can append to tuples. Tuples are immutable.

For more details on tuples, please see the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). For your use case, it seems like a `list` would be a better data type.